# Azure DevOps React Deployment: Unable to run the script on Kudu Service. Error: Error: Unable to fetch script status due to timeout

Tags: reactjs, azure, yaml, devops, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a CRA + Craco React application via Azure Devops. This is my YML file:

```yaml
# Node.js React Web App to Linux on Azure
# Build a Node.js React app and deploy it to Azure as a Linux web app.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- master

variables:

  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: '{REDACTED FOR SO}'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'frontend'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'public'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: '
            inputs:
              ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
              azureSubscription: 'My Subscription'
              appType: 'webAppLinux'
              WebAppName: 'frontend'
              packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              RuntimeStack: 'NODE|10.10'
              StartupCommand: 'npm run start'
              ScriptType: 'Inline Script'
              InlineScript: |
                npm install
                npm run build --if-present
```

The build tasks succeeds. However, the deployment fails after running for ~20 minutes, with the following error:

```
Starting: Azure App Service Deploy: 
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure App Service deploy
Description  : Deploy to Azure App Service a web, mobile, or API app using Docker, Java, .NET, .NET Core, Node.js, PHP, Python, or Ruby
Version      : 4.198.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/azureappservicetroubleshooting
==============================================================================
Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'frontend'
Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
Deploy logs can be viewed at https://{MYAPPSERVICENAME}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/62cf55c3f1434309b71a8334b2696fc9/log
Successfully deployed web package to App Service.
Trying to update App Service Application settings. Data: {"SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT":"1800"}
App Service Application settings are already present.
Executing given script on Kudu service.
##[error]Error: Unable to run the script on Kudu Service. Error: Error: Unable to fetch script status due to timeout. You can increase the timeout limit by setting 'appservicedeploy.retrytimeout' variable to number of minutes required.
Successfully updated deployment History at https://{MYAPPSERVICENAME}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/3641645137779498
App Service Application URL: http://{MYAPPSERVICENAME}.azurewebsites.net
Finishing: Azure App Service Deploy:
```

Answer (score 0):

**This YML solved my issues, along with upgrading Azure app service node version to 14.***

What I did is, I have moved the *npm install*  and *npm run build*  to build stage, and removed it from the deployment inline script stage.

So the package is ready before the deployment, after the successful unzip it will start the app using  **pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/build --no-daemon --spa**  as its running in a linux app service. (it works if your build directory is within wwwroot), if not please update the path accordingly

```
  # Node.js React Web App to Linux on Azure
# Build a Node.js React app and deploy it to Azure as a Linux web app.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- develop

variables:

  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: 'YOUR-SUBSCRIPTION'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'AZURE_APP_NAME'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'APP_ENV_NAME'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '14.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        npm install
      displayName: 'npm install'

    - script: |
        npm run build
      displayName: 'npm build'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: poultry-web-test'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              WebAppName: $(webAppName)
              packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              RuntimeStack: 'NODE|14-lts'
              StartupCommand: 'pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/build --no-daemon --spa'
```

Comment: @yunnosch here is the full YML in text format